# Append key and value to JSON file which is yielded from an element, in particular object of an Array without loosing previous data

Tags: javascript, cypress

My JSON looks like below

```
[
    {
     "key1":"value1"
     "key1.1":"value1.1"
    }

    {
     "key2":"value2"
     "key2.1":"value2.1"
    }
    
    { 
    "key3":value3
    "key3.1":value3.1
    }
]
```

I want to add one more key-value pair(e.g `"key1.2": "value1.2"`) in the first or any one of the objects. Using below, it's just adding the value only and removing all the older data

```
.then((data)=>{
  const value1.2 = data
 cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/array.json', value1.2, { flag: 'a+' })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the data inside the json file first then append the new key value pair before writing to file.

```
cy.readFile('cypress/fixtures/array.json').then((data) => {
  data.newKey = { "key1.2": "value1.2" }
  cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/array.json', JSON.stringify(data))
})
```